# Change localizable file

Tags: ios, string, restart, multilingual

I'm currently developing an application for IOS and I have four Localizable.strings files, each representing a different language. The thing is, i want to be able change the file that is being used without having to restart the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without restarting the App.

A work around is store the language and it's values in a database file or in a plist file. Then use the data from there. (Basically it is not a good idea)